# How do I get a variable that is stored in scene memory into an Operator?

Tags: python, uv-image-editor

I thought that I could get integers from user input in the UI panel and use them directly in a generic operator to scale the image, but I am stumped on how to get the scene info into the operator as it is now. Sorry about the code quality, but this is a cut and paste proof of concept first before I tidy things up.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import *

def initSceneProperties(scn):
    bpy.types.Scene.MyIntX = IntProperty(
        name = "Scale X", 
        description = "Enter an integer")
    scn['MyIntX'] = 1024

    bpy.types.Scene.MyIntY = IntProperty(
        name = "Scale Y", 
        description = "Enter an integer")
    scn['MyIntY'] = 1024
    return


initSceneProperties(bpy.context.scene)



class GenericOper(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Generic Operator"""
    bl_idname = "object.generic_operator" 


    bl_label = "Generic Operator Template"
    bl_options = { 'REGISTER', 'UNDO' }



    def execute(self, context):        



        for area in bpy.context.screen.areas :
            if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR' :
                my_img = area.spaces.active.image
                area.spaces.active.image = my_img


                my_img.scale(MyIntX,MyIntY)


        return {'FINISHED'}




class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Image Scale"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_imagescale"
    bl_space_type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    #bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scn = context.scene
        image = bpy.context.space_data.image

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Image Scale Test Panel", icon='WORLD_DATA')

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Active image is: " + image.name)
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(image, "name")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("object.generic_operator", text="scale it")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scn, 'MyIntX', icon='BLENDER', toggle=True)
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scn, 'MyIntY', icon='BLENDER', toggle=True)



        #row = layout.row()
        #row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)

    bpy.utils.register_class(GenericOper)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GenericOper)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Try `my_img.scale(context.scene.MyIntX, context.scene.MyIntY)`  [It's preferable not to use `CamelCase` for property names](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_best_practice.html)  Also rather than setting prop with `scene["blah"] = value`  recommend making it a default value in def eg `bpy.types.Scene.blah = IntProperty(default=1024)`

Comment: Can you add that as an answer so I can accept? I got it to work from what you gave advice on. I really appreciate the help on this.